# Testing a topic on embedded Artemis broker fails

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I have a problem with my tests. I have a Camel route that consumes messages from a topic.

```
from("artemis:topic:okosys.topic.kontostreng.endretprosjekt?acknowledgementMode=SESSION_TRANSACTED&bridgeErrorHandler=true&transacted=true&subscriptionId=GJEDNAprosjektokonomi&durable=true&shared=true")
```

But when I run tests with embedded broker it throws an exception.

```
2020-02-06 13:24:16,399;severity=INFO;thread=Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@60abf663);class=org.apache.activemq.audit.base;AMQ601265: User anonymous is creating a core consumer on target resource ServerSessionImpl() [with parameters: [0, GJEDNAprosjektokonomi, null, 0, false, true, null]]
2020-02-06 13:24:16,403;severity=INFO;thread=Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-remoting-threads-ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=f8df219f-48e3-11ea-81d8-a0155dd7b381-1795374719);class=org.apache.activemq.audit.base;AMQ601267: User anonymous is creating a core session on target resource ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=f8df219f-48e3-11ea-81d8-a0155dd7b381 [with parameters: [f93557f8-48e3-11ea-81d8-a0155dd7b381, null, ****, 102400, RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=f9230870-48e3-11ea-81d8-a0155dd7b381,clientID=null,nodeID=f8df219f-48e3-11ea-81d8-a0155dd7b381, transportConnection=InVMConnection [serverID=0, id=f9230870-48e3-11ea-81d8-a0155dd7b381]], false, false, false, false, null, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.CoreSessionCallback@20239ad, true, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.nullpm.NullStorageManager$2@7d09ea51,{}]]
2020-02-06 13:24:16,420;severity=ERROR;thread=Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@60abf663);class=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server;AMQ224016: Caught exception org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNonExistentQueueException: AMQ229017: Queue GJEDNAprosjektokonomi does not exist
```

Is there some kind of configuration error I've done here? Seems everything works when using straight queues...

We are using the SimpleJMS2 component. Wasn't able to make subscriptions work at all with regular JMS component.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `artemis` Camel component. Is that using the core protocol? Why aren't you using the `jms` Camel component?

Comment: Updated description, sorry for the lack of info. We are using SimpleJMS2 component.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any info on the `SimpleJMS2` component. Do you have a link for reference? If you're using a custom component of some kind you'll have to provide more details about it. Not much help can be provided with the details you've given so far.

Comment: Camel Simple JMS 2 Docs: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sjms2-component.html

Comment: The URI format for the Simple JMS 2 component starts with `sjms2` but you are using `artemis` in your URI. Can you clarify this?